# YII : Build a web service in order to get session another application

Tags: php, web-services, yii

I wanna fetch a session from non-yii application into yii application. From some literature that i've been red, i found that the best solution is embedding a web service between them. Actually, i never try this. Could somebody give me some suggestion? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the applications are on the same server you could use a database structured like mySql or memcache to save your sessions, that way you can read them out with your yii application.

If they are not on the same server i suggest you write an API (like with REST or Node.js) to share session data.

Althought a better option would be to store your data not in the session but somewhere else that is accesible to both apps and store a reference to that data in both seperate sessions.